# Sql Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a Stored Procedure this is what I have so far

```
Create procedure sp_Create_order
@P_nafn varchar(50),
@P_fj int,
@P_sótt datetime,
@F_kt varchar(10),
@V_nr int,
@L_id int

as 
begin
    set nocount on

if exists(
   select * from Lotur
   where L_id=@L_id and
   @P_sótt between L_hefst and L_pfrest
)
INSERT INTO Pantar(P_nafn, P_fj, P_sótt, F_kt, V_nr, L_id) 
VALUES (@P_nafn, @P_fj, @P_sótt, @F_kt, @V_nr, @L_id)
end
```

but I am getting these errors

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_Create_order, Line 14 Incorrect
>   syntax near ' '.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_Create_order, Line 15 Incorrect
>   syntax near ' '.

on these lines

```
select * from Lotur
where L_id=@L_id
```

and

`@P_sótt`, `L_hefst` and `L_pfrest`
are all dates and I am tryng to put a condition on saying that nothing should be Inserted unless `@P_sótt` is equal to or between `L_hefst` and `L_pfrest`

Comment: What version and flavor of SQL are you using?  I was able to create this procedure without errors on SQL Server 2000 and 2005.

Comment: I'm using mssql 2005 as soon as I replased * whith L_id it started Working

Answer (score 1):

- Please use meaningful names for your variables
- Do not create sp for every thing like the one above
- Modify the query to have SELECT L_ID NOT SELECT *
- As for the error, probably you have mistyped something

Comment: Does select * really matter if it's inside an exists?

Comment: The procedure as is compiles and ran for me under SQL Server 2005, it's possibly some other strange problem.

Comment: Not sure Jeffrey...query optimizer maybe be able to optimize it, but still there's no reason to "select *"

Comment: I'd disagree on your 2nd point -- we create stored procs for ALL database access.  No direct SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs allowed.

Comment: There's a huge debate on the 2nd point. My preference is to not use sp for every trivial thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend prefixing your Stored Procedure with **sp_**. [Performance](http://www.sqlmag.com/articles/index.cfm?articleid=23011&) is at least one reason why it's a bad idea.

Your stored procedure compiled ok for me. Another recommendation would be to use

```
if exists (
   select 1 
   from 
       Lotur
   where 
       L_id= @L_id 
       and @P_sótt between L_hefst and L_pfrest
)
```

as opposed to `SELECT *`. Did you get the error when compiling or trying to use it?

**EDIT:**

In response to your post about raising errors, you might want to look at [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Here is an [example of how to use it in Stored procedures](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/handling-errors-in-stored-procedures)

Comment: Is this still an issue with SQL 2005/2008? That article you referenced  was from 2001.

Comment: IMHO, you should never use sp_ at the start of your own stored procedures. SQL Server will always look in master first

Comment: Run the profiler and try it :) I found it to be the case in 2005 - I don't know about 2008 but I suspect the same, considering MS advise against the practice